# Redis connection with go lang

Tags: go, redis

I am getting

> **dial : unknown network error**

when i try to connect redis in go lang like this :

```
var client *redis.Client

client = redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
    Addr : "localhost:6379",
    Password:"",
    DB       : 0,
});
```

Why i am getting this error,please help.

Comment: Connection setup looks correct.
This error - are you getting it from _, err := client.Ping().Result() ?

Comment: yes i am getting this error in that code

Comment: Please tell us which redis client you are using and the line of code where the error is returned.

Comment: "unknown network error" is an error from Go's net package, so my only conclusion would be some issue with a driver or connection to redis. 
For example: "gopkg.in/redis.v5" redis package on Go .7.4 with an official alpine redis Docker and this setup works fine. If I intentionally mess credentials/host/port/container state - I get expected redis errors. Could not reproduce unknown network.
Try connecting to a different redis server to double-check.

Comment: İ am using redis-cli 3.0.6 and inside my project i am using this library "gopkg.in/redis.v2" .

In this line  --> pong,err := client.Ping().Result()

Comment: If you're going to use that redis client, I highly recommend you use a more up to date version. There's been a lot of improvements in the past 3 years.

Answer (score 6):

You're not providing a network parameter for the Dialer:

```
client := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
    Network:  "tcp",
    Addr:     "localhost:6379",
    Password: "",
    DB:       0,
})
```

Or use [`NewTCPClient`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/redis.v2#NewTCPClient), which sets the "tcp" network parameter for you.

Comment: @devguy When an answer is correct and solves your problem, please accept it. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers